# What's the pattern?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

I went to a library and found a book which contained puzzles. I found this puzzle, and decoded it. I showed it to my friends, and they couldn't figure out. I then posted it on this website...

**Find the pattern in these numbers:**

```
12, 18, 24, 72, 16, 8, 4, 24, 30, 36, 42, 126, 28, 14, 7, 5040
```

<sub>Note: for stuff such as +5 for 3, then +10 for 1, repeat is allowed</sub>

Hint:

> The first 3 are adding the number which is the square root of 9 + the square root of 9.

Comment: If you're allowing answers like "+5 for 3, then +10 for 1" where the "pattern" changes every now and then, what advantage do such answers have over just, y'know, listing the numbers?

Comment: Sorry, just was being unclear.

Comment: I don't think I understand that answer.

Comment: I meant i was being unclear. Though, it is a valid pattern and it is in the numbers you see 2 times (the pattern starts over at the 30 number, next to 24.)

Comment: I agree with Sconibulus's analysis, but personally I wouldn't call this "a valid pattern".

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please edit your post to include irrelevant, random noise surrounding the text in order to make people think that your question is something more than it actually is. You can write a short story surrounding the text, like you are a prisoner in a UFO and the only way to survive is to figure out the next number in the sequence. You might wish to add that these numbers are the number of consecutive footsteps you overhear; or your heartrate/sec; or whatever. Please read [what not to do](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do).

Comment: I hope Matsmath's advice isn't intended entirely seriously. I don't think any puzzle is much improved by adding "irrelevant, random noise" in that fashion.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I believe Red Herrings are a fundamental tools in puzzle creation. A clock on the wall, a place, a name, or a timestamp could each misguide the adventurous puzzle-solvers. Those will make any puzzle more difficult. How is it not any improvement?

Comment: @Matsmath: "Difficult" is not the same thing as "good". Irrelevant information makes puzzles worse - ideally, a puzzle will use all of its information.

Comment: I don't believe this deserved that many downvotes...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's something resembling

> 12,18,24 = +6
> 24,72 = x3
> 72,16 = *2/9 
> 16,8,4 = /2
> 4,24 = !
> 24,30,36,42 = +6
> 42,126 = *3
> 126,28 = *2/9
> 28,14,7 = /2
> 7,5040 = !

So the final sequence is probably:

> 12, 18, 24, 72, 16, 8, 4, 24, 30, 36, 42, 126, 28, 14, 7, 5040, 5046, 5052, 5058, 5064, 15192, 3376, 1688, 844, 844! (which I'm not even going to try to do)...

Comment: You were pretty close. It does have a factorial, division and multiplication, and it's clear it has addition. The values are a bit off, though.

Comment: It looks to me as if Sconibulus's description does match what your sequence does. Are you saying you have another sequence of operations in mind that's "better" somehow? Is it better because it's simpler, or what?

Comment: No, just that this one is very close but not the actual answer.

Comment: Sconibulus' sequence seems to be perfect (+1), maybe except for the fact that it has 2 cycle that do not have a perfect match. In the firs cycle  + 6 is made two times, three times in the second. So he can transform 24 into 30 for example multiplying by 5/4 or adding the sum of its digits (2+4 = 6). So the sequence repeats itself 2 times but there is no number after 5040 to check the last operation. +6, +6, x3 ,x3, x2/9, /2, /2, !, x5/4, and again.